# How to structure listen and disseminate with asyncio websockets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write a server using asyncio/websockets that listens to a single websocket connection on one port, and when it gets a message, it sends that to all of the websockets that are listening to it on a separate port. There could be hundreds of clients on the second port, so I know I need to use the non-blocking `await websocket.send(msg)`. But I can't figure out how to structure this listen/disseminate paradigm in terms of the event loops.

Here's my first attempt:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import time

LISTEN_PORT = 8080
SPEAK_PORT = 8081

audience = []

async def add_audience_member(websocket, path):
    global audience
    print('New audience member!')
    audience.append(websocket)

async def add_source(websocket, path):
    global audience
    while True:
        msg = await websocket.recv()
        for ws in audience:
            await ws.send(msg + ' ' + str(time.time()))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(websockets.serve(add_audience_member, HOST, SPEAK_PORT))
loop.run_until_complete(websockets.serve(add_source, HOST, LISTEN_PORT))
loop.run_forever()
```

Then I have a client running:

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection('ws://{}:{}'.format(HOST, 8081))
while True:
    data = ws.recv(); print data
```

The problem is that add_audience_member closes the connection as soon as it adds the new websocket to the audience list, so I get the error:

```
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection is already closed.
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Sorry, just updated with my attempts!

Comment: I haven't used websockets, so this is a comment rather than an answer. The problem might be that `add_audience_member` has _exited_ too soon. Instead. Try adding `await asyncio.Event()` at the end of `add_audience_member` and see if it fixes the problem. If it does, then you would store the even somewhere and use its `set()` method to cause `add_audience_member` to exit and remove the member from the global audience list. (A more proper name for the function would then be `communicate_with_audience_member`.)

Comment: Also, `await ws.send()` is not really non-blocking if you `await` it. (It is non-blocking in the sense that it doesn't block the whole event loop, but it certainly blocks `add_source`.) To make it truly asynchronous you should use `loop.create_task(ws.send())`.